# Using ncat inside bash script

Tags: json, bash, curl, webhooks, netcat

I'm doing simple http-server on bash with ncat, which should receive some json in POST and then compile from received json another one with variables replacement. How to make the script running forward after first loop?

"Server A" sends some json to "Server B". "Server B" - is a docker container with some script inside. "Server C" is the destination. The script is below

The first part, starting ncat on 5000 port, redirecting all input to the file

```
#!/bin/bash

ncat -lk 5000 > /tmp/ncat.txt
```

Replacing variables from income json

```
id=$(echo $(date +%s))
name=$(cat /tmp/ncat.txt | grep receiver | jq -r '.alerts[].labels.alertname')
status_current=$(cat /tmp/ncat.txt | grep receiver | jq -r '.status')
info=$(cat /tmp/ncat.txt | grep receiver | jq -r '.commonAnnotations.message')
```

Sending recompiled json to "Server C"

```
curl http://server-c/webhook -X POST -d '
{
  "id":"'"$id"'",
  "name":"'"$name"'",
  "status_current":"'"$status_current"'",
  "info":"'"$info"'"
}'
```

The question is: after receiving the first request, the scripts stops to work. How to make a loop there? Like: ncat listening the port, receiving json, recompiling vars, executing curl, ncat listening the port...
Second question: when i'm sending dummy json from "Server A" (simple curl -X POST -d ''), the second step oof the script will not execute until i break (ctrl+c) the curl request.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd use a fifo instead of a static file

Comment: Please update your question with the output of the netcat command